# How can I provide Tor browsing through my Wordpress site?

Tags: onion-services

I'd like to create a page on my Wordpress site which features something like a frame where visitors to my site can browse the web through Tor.

How would I go about constructing such a feature? I don't see any plugins doing this specifically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While providing that type of feature would defeat the purpose of using tor, you could create an iframe using the .onion address and appending .to at the end.

Example: 
http://2v7ibl5u4pbemwiz.onion
   would change to
http://2v7ibl5u4pbemwiz.onion.to

You should be able to create a seperate page and modify the HTML. There are plugins to let you add custom HTML as a side panel as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how Tor works. Even if this were feasible, your visitors would have no way to know if you're tracking their browsing, which would pretty much defeat the purpose of anonymous browsing.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the tracking issue. I just figured a plugin could connect people, but one doesn't exist. I'm sure it would involve backend packages to be installed to send the connection to tor through. If it were an open-source, peer-reviewed plugin, that might provide reassurance that tracking weren't occurring.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this would defeat a lot of the benefits of Tor.

But we shouldn't gatekeep on SE. OP may have a legitimate use-case.

#### Tor2Web

Look into Tor2Web:

- https://github.com/tor2web/Tor2web

Tor2Web was originally [designed by Aaron Swartz and Virgil Griffith in 2008](https://blog.torproject.org/quick-thoughts-tor2web) to provide a means for users without tor to visit .onion websites from the clearnet -- thus providing anonymity to the server, but not to the client.